# Metal: limit MTLRenderCommandEncoder texture loading to only part of texture

Tags: swift, textures, metal

I do have a Metal rendering pipeline setup which encodes render commands and operates on a  `texture: MTLTexture` object to load and store the output. This `texture` is rather large and and **each render command just operates on a small fraction of the whole texture**. The basic setup is roughly the following:

```
// texture: MTLTexture, pipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState, commandBuffer: MTLCommandBuffer

// create and setup MTLRenderPassDescriptor with loadAction = .load
let renderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
if let attachment = self.renderPassDescriptor?.colorAttachments[0] {
    attachment.clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    attachment.texture = texture // texture size is rather large
    attachment.loadAction = .load
    attachment.storeAction = .store
}

// create MTLRenderCommandEncoder
guard let renderCommandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor) else { return }

// limit rendering to small fraction of texture
let scissorRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: 0.1 * CGSize(width: CGFloat(texture.width), height: CGFloat(texture.height))) // create rect begin small fraction of texture rect
let metalScissorRect = MTLScissorRect(x: Int(scissorRect.origin.x), y: Int(scissorRect.origin.y), width: Int(scissorRect.width), height: Int(scissorRect.height))
            renderCommandEncoder.setScissorRect(metalScissorRect)

renderCommandEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)
renderCommandEncoder.setScissorRect(metalScissorRect)

// encode some commands here

renderCommandEncoder.endEncoding()
```

In practice many `renderCommandEncoder` objects are created, each time just operating on a small fraction of the texture. **Unfortunately, each time a `renderCommandEncoder` is commited the whole texture is loaded** and stored at the end, which is specified by the `renderPassDescriptor` due to the corresponding setting of its colorAttachment `loadAction` and `storeAction`.

My Question is:
**Is it possible to limit the load and store process to a region of `texture`?** (in order to avoid wasting computation time for loading and storing huge parts of the texture when only a small part is needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach, to avoid loading and storing the entire texture into the render pipeline, could be the following, assuming your scissor rectangle is constant between drawcalls:

1. Blit (MTLBlitCommandEncoder) the region of interest from the large texture to a smaller(e.g. the size of your scissor rectangle) intermediate texture.
2. Load and store, and draw/operate only on the smaller intermediate texture.
3. When done encoding, blit back the result to the original source region of the larger texture.

This way you load and store only the region of interest in your pipeline, with only the added constant memory cost of maintaining a smaller intermediate texture(assuming region of interest is constant between drawcalls).

*Blitting is a fast operation and the above method should thus optimize your current pipeline.*

Comment: I thought about that and this is actually my current implementation. One of the problems for me with this approach is that creating a small texture every time seems to be very inefficient due to memory allocation. So I currently use a large texture to copy to, which is large enough for all possible scissorRect sizes, and use this texture with a loadAction of .dontCare. Any ideas on how to obtain the small texture without needing to allocate new memory? (I thought of something like a different view of the original large `texture`, but such a thing does not seem to exist).

Comment: You allocate the smaller texture/buffer up-front (only once), not for every frame. But that was based on the assumption that you had a constant scissor rect, not variable rects, as you said. If your larger texture is used only in the renderpass without the need to store, then a tip would be to use MTLStorageMode.memoryless(only accessible by the GPU)  for it.