# A-Buffer method with metal and memory economy

Tags: metal

I have an idea to extend linked list by reducing rendering area, i.e by using a small render target that then blitted into main render target, tile by tile.
The main problem is how to render into a small render target as it would be just a scissor rect of main render target?
The main idea of using small render target is taken there - [Metal: limit MTLRenderCommandEncoder texture loading to only part of texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59111013/metal-limit-mtlrendercommandencoder-texture-loading-to-only-part-of-texture)

**UPD**
This is not for realtime rendering

Comment: This does not sound like a good idea, unless you are going to basically write your own tiler. The problem is, you don't know where your geometry is on a screen, and to know that, you need to replicate what the hardware already does for you on a tile stage (for Apple GPUs).

Comment: Yes, I know that can seriously reduce fps and I have to redraw whole scene(or calculate which meshes is visible in tile) each time, but for non realtime rendering I don't know a better way